# symfony2 render action array to more than 1 template

Tags: symfony, view, rendering

I am new to Symfony (and PHP as well). I currently have a method indexAction in my Controller which renders an array of objects ($results) to the index view (index.html.twig template) - this part works.

I would like to use the SAME array that I am rendering in index.html.twig in a different view page. Is it possible to render an array to multiple templates?

I've tried adding a 2nd render statement, but it doesn't work (I get an error saying that the array being called in the 2nd template does not exist - thus only the 1st render statement is working). I've thought about copying and pasting the content of indexAction into get_stuffAction (both methods in the same controller), but I think this is probably not the best way to proceed (lots of redundant code).

```
return $this->render('TryBundle:Try:index.html.twig',  array('results'=>$results));
return $this->render('TryBundle:Try:get_stuff.html.twig',  array('results'=>$results));
```

Just wondering if someone knows how to render an array to multiple views, or if I can somehow use the array created in indexAction function in the get_stuffAction function.

Thank you kindly for your time!

Comment: Yeah, but you can't return the user multiple views, just one per request. If you want you can include a view in another passing the same array you passed into the first view

Comment: That's an idea. How can I include the same array in another view? I've already tried "just using it" in TWIG, but I get an error along the lines of "variable does not exist".

Comment: First of all, are the 2 views merged into the same controller call? that way you can include a template from another passing the array as the second parameter of the include function

Comment: Currently, my 2 views are called as above, but only the 1st one works used. I've also tried merging into to the same rendering statement, but this was wrong too; return $this->render('TryBundle:Try:index.html.twig', 'TryBundle:Try:get_stuff.html.twig',  array('results'=>$results));  for which I get an error message Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller::render() must be of the type array, string given,.."

Comment: You can't render 2 views, the only way to merge them is to created a 3rd template with {% render %} called into the 3rd template including the other 2 templates

Comment: Thanks for the help - I'll try to implement this. Would you happen to know of a good tutorial (easy to understand for newbies)? Thank you again!

Comment: The symfony guide for templates http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html actually covers the template inclusion and everything you could need for templating

Answer (score 2):

why don't you create a method in your controller to get the result, then in each action just call that method for the data you want.